# Recommendation using Client side performance monitoring (boomerang/jiffy/episodes)

Tags: performance, performance-monitoring, javascript

There are a few Client-side JavaScript libraries that check web-site performance on the client side:

- Jiffy (http://code.google.com/p/jiffy-web/)
- Episodes (http://stevesouders.com/episodes/) by Steve Sounders
- Boomerang (http://yahoo.github.com/boomerang/doc/) by Yahoo!

Have you used any of them or a similar too?
What did you use for the server-side? for reporting?
Is this a recommended approach?
If not, how should I monitor my web-site performance from the end-user's view?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 2009 article that discusses Jiffy and Episodes:

http://wimleers.com/article/page-loading-profiling-tools

Summary:

- Jiffy had not been updated since first release.
- Episodes was favored over Jiffy.
- Boomerang was not mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. Did you try using any of them?

Comment: boomerang was released around May 2010 hence it was not mentioned in the 2009 article.